# Tensorflow accuracy is way lower then expected

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I had a LSTM time-series binary classification model with a very poor accuracy.
I was not sure whether there was something wrong with features data or my model was completely  incorrect.

So I updated target labels of both training and validation data with a dummy pattern like

```
if Feature[13] > Feature[5] then target = 0 else target = 1
```

Now I know that there is an exact pattern in my data. if feature13 is bigger, then target is 1.
But still the accuracy of my model is not going higher than 0.9.

Could you please shed some light?

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, 60, 256)           300032
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 60, 256)           0
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_7 (LSTM)                (None, 60, 256)           525312
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 60, 256)           0
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_8 (LSTM)                (None, 256)               525312
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 32)                8224
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)          (None, 32)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 33
=================================================================
Total params: 1,358,913
Trainable params: 1,358,913
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: what is a label when input[0, 0, 13] > input[0, 0, 5], but input[0, 1, 13] < input[0, 1, 5] ?

Comment: it is always same. if input[:,5]> input[:,13] then it is 1 . Label depends on just one column in my dummy data. The rest of the data is useless.

Comment: input[:, 5] is array

Comment: sorry. So the label depends on just one column in input. the data in other columns does not matter.

Comment: Those dropouts might result in underfitting, did you try removing them?

Comment: @Kenank what do you mean by column ? are you comparing input[0,0,13] with input[0,0,5] ? Or input[0,13,0] with input[0,5,0] ?

Comment: I compare numbers, not arrays.

Comment: Yes, I removed drop outs, also tried different drop-out ratios. It is always same.